# How to find out if workspace added or removed your Slack App?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I have some questions about Slack App after Public Distribution is activated.

Our team has developed a Slack App with bot and incoming webhook features, and we have activated public distribution for this Slack App, and added the "Add to Slack" button on our product webpage.

Questions:

1. Is there any way to find out what workspaces have added our Slack App?  I understand that via the Add-to-Slack flow, we would know when a workspace has added the Slack App along with the resulting bot access token and webhook.  But is that the only way to keep track?  Is there no API to just list the workspaces, resulting bot, and webhook?
2. Is there any way to find out which workspaces have removed our Slack App?  I can infer that information by doing an users.list API call using the bot access token.  If it says token invalid, then I can guess that the workspace has removed the Slack App.  Is there no other direct API to find out if a workspace has removed the Slack App?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Is there any way to find out what workspaces have added our Slack App?
>      I understand that via the Add-to-Slack flow, we would know when a
>      workspace has added the Slack App along with the resulting bot access
>      token and webhook. But is that the only way to keep track? Is there no
>      API to just list the workspaces, resulting bot, and webhook?

This is the only way (to track workspace during installation flow). At least for now, I saw such a feature in mid/long term plans for Slack API team.

> 2. Is there any way to find out which workspaces have removed our Slack
>      App? I can infer that information by doing an users.list API call
>      using the bot access token. If it says token invalid, then I can guess
>      that the workspace has removed the Slack App. Is there no other direct
>      API to find out if a workspace has removed the Slack App?

Take a look at [app_uninstalled](https://api.slack.com/events/app_uninstalled) and [tokens_revoked](https://api.slack.com/events/tokens_revoked) API events.